# Java readFile from byte x to byte y

Tags: java

Im trying to read a text file, x bytes at a time into a variable, process each "chunk" and write it to another file.

So far all I can do sucessfully is:

```
// read each line at a time:
while ( ( str = in.readLine() ) != null){ ....
```

Is it possible to specify something like...  str = in.readBytes( 320 up to 400 ) ... ???

Any thoughts or comments welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`read(byte[])`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])).

So you would something like:

```
InputStream in; // initialized however you're doing
int bytesRead = 0;
byte bytes[60]; // We'll read in up to 60 bytes at a time
while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    // bytesRead is = to the number of bytes actually read
    // bytes array holds the next 'bytesRead' number of bytes
}
```